# A few questions about the CalendarView

Tags: android

1. There is a standard calendar in Android. How do I set different backgrounds for specific days? e.g. 1, 11, 14 and 17 have a red background; 2, 12 have a green background, etc.?
2. What event happens when you click on the current day? I have an event when you click on any day, but if you click on the one that is in focus, it does not work.

   ```
   public class Conference extends Fragment implements CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener {
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conference, null);
           CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
           calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
           return v;
           @Override
           public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(),year+" "+month+" "+dayOfMonth,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition on days like if its 1 11 or etc ... then using find view By id give R.layout.XXX and then set Background Color from there .. 
if u want to use diffrent background for each day u can put a loop also and then increase the value of background color.. like for day 12 you will loop from 1 to 12 and then keep on increasing background color

Comment: I understand how to do it logically. I do not know how to apply it to the calendar